# Can't get the description from model to override and show

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this working in another app just fine, exact same code and everything is linked in storyboard? I have no Idea what is going on. It seems as the assignmentInfo.className string is kept to nul. and the description method is also nul. Take a look:

AddEditViewController.h -

```
{
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateTimePicker;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *className;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *assignmentTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *assignmentDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISwitch *procrastinationNotificationSwitch;
@property (nonatomic,strong)AssignmentInfo *assignmentInfo;
- (IBAction)addTheInfo:(id)sender;
```

AddEditViewController.m -

```
{
    if (!_assignmentInfo) {
        _assignmentInfo = [[AssignmentInfo alloc]init];
    }
    return _assignmentInfo;


}

- (IBAction)addTheInfo:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateTimePicker.date];
    self.assignmentInfo.className = self.className.text;
    self.assignmentInfo.assignmentTitle = self.assignmentTitle.text;
    self.assignmentInfo.assignmentDescription = self.assignmentDescription.text;
    self.assignmentInfo.dateTimeString = dateTimeString;
    NSLog(@"%@",self.assignmentInfo.className);    
    NSLog(@"%@",self.assignmentInfo.description);

    [self presentMessage:self.assignmentInfo.description];



}
```

AssignmentInfo.h -

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *className;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *assignmentDescription;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *assignmentTitle;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *dateTimeString;

@property (nonatomic)bool notifcationStatus;
```

AssignmentInfo.m -

```
-(NSString *)description
{

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class: %@\r Assignment Title: %@ \rAssignment Description: %@ \rDue: %@ \r%s", self.className, self.assignmentTitle, self.assignmentDescription, self.dateTimeString,self.notifcationStatus ? "Notification On" : "Notification Off"];
}
```

Comment: Where have you initialized the `assignmentInfo`?

Comment: @Zen in the AddEditViewController I edited the code above to show.

Comment: Did you make sure that its not `nil` before you set its properties in your `IBAction`? I think its still `nil` there.

Comment: @Zen thanks for your help I actually did forget to init first then I had fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it incorrect before :

```
-(AssignmentInfo *)classObject
{
    if (!_assignmentInfo) {
        _assignmentInfo = [[AssignmentInfo alloc]init];
    }
    return _assignmentInfo;


}
```

After:

```
-(AssignmentInfo *)assignmentInfo
{
    if (!_assignmentInfo) {
        _assignmentInfo = [[AssignmentInfo alloc]init];
    }
    return _assignmentInfo;


}
```

Just a silly mistake.